# Java Frameworks

Tags: java, frameworks

Recently I've come across many different frameworks for creating web apps in Java such as: Play!, Wicket, Grails, Lift, and Tapestry. What exactly is a framework and what are the benefits of using one? Additionally, I would like to try one out. I want a framework that is lightweight and easy to use and get started with, since my web development knowledge is very limited. Which one would you recommend?

Also I'm sure this question has been asked a dozen times, but it's quite tedious to have to search through past questions to find the answer your looking for.

Comment: Searching for answers isn't nearly as tedious as answering the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Lift is for Scala.

Tapestry is a UI-only framework.

Grails is Groovy, Spring, and Hibernate combined into a Ruby On Rails-like environment for rapidly creating CRUD web apps.

Play! and Wicket deserve the moniker of framework.

You don't mention Spring; you should look at it.  That's what I would recommend.  It's a combination of dependency injection, aspect oriented programming, and great modules for persistence, web and portal MVC, remoting, declarative transactions, message driven POJOs, and lots more.  It has a great deal of mindshare and traction.  It's been purchased by VMWare, so it's going to be around for a while.

You'll need more than a framework to do web development.  In all cases, you can't do web development without HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: Ahh, "Spring", well it's certainly the conservative answer. Still, it has some bloat, kitchen-sink and bandwagon attributes nowadays doesn't it?

Comment: One man's bandwagon is another's traction.  Bloat?  Somebody's gotta write some code.  Kitchen sink?  You don't have to use all of it, just what you need.  What's your better answer, Crusader?  Writing it all yourself?  Pico Container is a very good idea, but it's JUST DI/IoC.  Spring has a lot more.  They aren't 1:1.

Comment: What do you think about Jboss Seam

Comment: I don't think about Seam.  It's JBOSS using JSF and Hibernate.  Far too heavy for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something quick and light, I think Play! framework suits you. The MVC architecture made it similar to Ruby on Rails. Unlike the traditional Java framework, it automatically recompile the Java source code when changes are made, therefore shorten the software development cycle from coding->compiling->testing to coding->testing.

Answer (score 1):

A framework is something like a toolbox you can use for building. Benefits of using one would include saving time, not reinventing the wheel and lots more. This includes frameworks written in other languages.

I assume you're versed in Java, then my personal recommendation would be to give Play! a look and spend something building something in it before you actually have to try the other heavyweights (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

I won't disagree with anyone who says "learn the basics of servlets first". Since you're asking for recommendations, add **PicoContainer** to the list.

Pico is like Spring in that it does dependency injection and supports test driven development, but they do it in a cleaner (IMO) more "Java like" way by preferring constructors and *not* using ridiculous xml configuration context files like Spring apps (usually) do. (Helps reduce some of what would be xml caused run-time errors by replacing them with preferable Java code compile-time errors.)

Another nice thing about it is that it's a tiny little framework which makes great attempts to avoid dozens of dependencies and jar bloat (something the Spring maintainers should take notice of). The downside (there's always one, of course) is that it's a small community. (Then again, all the Spring resources out there in Google are somewhat polluted by now with information on past/different versions of this ever-evolving framework, so more isn't always better.)

Comment: Six years later: Lots of interest in Spring and Spring Boot; not much for Pico Container.  https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=pico%20container%2C%20spring%20framework&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT%2B5