# Strategy to integrate serial communication devices with JSF 2 application

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, communication

I am using jsf 2.2 and primefaces 5.1 with mysql database back end. Browser clients need to connect some serial devices with the JSF application. These are medical devices, some of these require user interaction in browser application and some don't. What will be the better strategy to handle these devices with the JSF application. 
At the moment i have a Multi-threaded Java desktop application that is handling this communication but there is a lot of lacking in terms of scalability, user experience and architecture. I am well versed in developing Java desktop serial communication software but for this project
1. Should i be writing web services for each type of device?
2. Can web services handle user interactive session with such devices?
Your advice on a strategic level will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this whiteboard question without any piece of code belongs on programmers.se.

Comment: This is a programming question because i am not sure whether to write a  Java Desktop Application or a web service for this particular requirement. There are hundreds of questions on stack overflow without code specially when people ask about java frameworks e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486210/java-frameworks

Comment: Just idea: You can write Java desktop application (i see you already have that) to collect data from all devices, send them to web API and save data to database. You can load data from database and show on JSF page.  So you don't need to write web services for each device type, but yes you will need to write logic to communicate with each device.

Comment: @jNick: Thanks for your input. Here each device type interacts with different protocol i.e. different variants of ASTM protocol. My desktop java application has a proper class hierarchy to identify and handle such requests on the basic of the serial port it is communicating. If i write a web service, can i distinguish the physical end point, if there are more than one device connected? As i already told that i don't know much about web services. I'd start reading on web services if i know that this is the right way.

Comment: @UmairNaqvi That is how i would do it. Web services are used for client server communication. Just don't write web service for each device type, make it generic. Your desktop application will get device data, you can map it to some domain object and push to  web service. Later on server (webservice) you can process this data (maybe first save it in database and process later). Good luck and let us know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically a browser is not allowed access a hosts serial port for security reasons, but there is at least one plugin available which allows this:

- http://fabacademy.org/archives/content/tutorials/12_Interface_and_Application_Programming/seriality/index.htm

You can also access the serial port with a Google Chrome App:

- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial

Depending on your use case this may be enough for you. If you are looking for all the power of a typical desktop client app, but based in the browser then Mozilla has some goals that are possibly similar - you can see the latest here, but I don't think it will meet your immediate needs now:

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI

Comment: Thanks Mick. It does not solve my problem but it gave me ideas and guide me where to look.